# Firestore using 2 Reads for adding a Document with a Timestamp

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I wanna set up a basic chat with Firestore and while implementing it I Noticed that the Listener actually registers 2 Events for 1 Document being added.

Here is the Code to add a Document:

```
      const chatRef = this.$fireStore.collection('chats/global/messages');

      chatRef.add({
        displayName: 'Prof Dr Barcode',
        content: this.newMsg,
        timestamp: this.$fireStoreObj.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
      });
```

And my listener looks like this:

```
const chatRef = this.$fireStore.collection('chats/global/messages');

const initialRef = chatRef.limit(10).orderBy('timestamp');

initialRef.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
  querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
    console.log(change.type);
    if (change.type === 'added') {
      this.messages.push(change.doc.data());
    }
  });
});
```

Now the `change.type` console log triggers twice for each document added. Once with `added` and once with `modified`, while investigating I saw that when I log myself the Document in the Listener it gets logged twice, at first with the `added` event the timestamp field is `null`, then instantly it triggers again with `modified` and the `timestamp` field is populated.

I dont think this is the correct way Firestore should behave?

Answer (score 1):

What you're observing is the expected behavior.  This is because the Firestore client SDK writes the new document to the local cache first, immediately, and all listeners are notified of the change as an "added" change.  Because you wrote a server timestamp, that final value gets interpreted after the document in synchronized to the server (not on the client), which results in a change to the timestamp field.  That change gets synchronized to the client, resulting in a "modified" change on the client.

If you remove the server timestamp, you should not see the additional modification, as the server now has nothing to add to the document that the client didn't already know about.